# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError cannot get the posts for each user for some reason Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

In the rails console I am inputing User.first.posts and i am getting this error ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :likes in model User
from

USER MODEL

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    has_many :posts
    has_many :comments
    has_many :posts, through: :likes

    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

POSTS MODEL

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
has_many :likes
has_many :users, through: :likes
def number_of_comments
    comments.length
end
def number_of_likes
    likes.length
end
```

end

LIKES MODEL

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
end
```

Im only showing you the likes model because its popping up in the error but i just want all the posts for each user so if i type User.first.posts all their posts will show up

Comment: I think there's a typo in your `User` model. You have 2 associations for `posts`. Maybe what you meant for one of those is `has_many :likes, through: :posts`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually define the `likes` assocation that you're defining the indirect assocation through:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :likes # this was missing
  has_many :posts, through: :likes
end
```

But you also have two different assocations between users and posts that are sharing the same name - you actually need something more like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts # posts that this user has created
  has_many :likes 
  has_many :liked_posts, 
     through: :likes,
     source: :post
end
```

Comment: You need to have the association in both models. I downvoted because it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Have you tried my solution to say that it's not the answer for the question? You don't need to have both association since you are using "has_many through".  Might want to check this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score -1):

There's seems to be a typo in your `User` model. There are 2 associations for `posts`.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    has_many :posts
    has_many :comments
    # has_many :posts, through: :likes # <-- this i think is the culprit.
    # it should be like this:
    has_many :likes, through: :posts

    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Comment: This doesn't actually fix the problem as the likes model is used as the join table.

Comment: It will work since `post` belongs to `user` and `post has_many :likes`. Therefore, you can get the `likes` through `posts`. I dunno how did you arrive at that conclusion. lol